# showMessageBox icon in renderer process?

Tags: javascript, electron

**Election v8.0.0; macOS 10.14.5**

Has anyone had success getting an icon to display with `dialog.showMessageBox` in the `renderer` process?

I'm able to get the icon to work from the `main` process but not from a `renderer` process. Same with `Notifications` – no icon but no errors. I can console.log the `nativeImage` so I know it is getting created but I'm still getting the default Electron icon.

I could probably do a workaround by messaging `main`, displaying the `showMessageBox`, sending back the result, etc. but that is more spaghetti code than I'd like.

```
 const iconPath = upath.toUnix(upath.join(__dirname, "assets", "icon.png"));
 //debuging:
 var fileExists = fs.existsSync(iconPath)
 console.log('fileExists', fileExists);

 const dialogIcon = nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath);
 //debuging:
 console.log('dialogIcon', dialogIcon);

var options = {
    type: 'question',
    buttons: ['&Yes', '&No'],
    title: 'Delete Event',
    icon: dialogIcon,
    normalizeAccessKeys: true,
    message: 'Permanently delete event?'
};

const win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
dialog.showMessageBox(win, options)
    .then((choice) => {
        if (choice.response === 0) {
            // do something
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to use a `nativeImage` with the `dialog` module in a `render` process, the `nativeImage` needs to be accessed through `remote` even though `nativeImage` is available to both `main` and `render` contexts:

```
const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron');
```

**Wrong:**

```
const { ipcRenderer, remote, nativeImage } = require('electron');
```

**Right:**

```
const { BrowserWindow, dialog, nativeImage } = require('electron').remote;
```